# Where is user profile information stored in the Dotnetnuke database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, dotnetnuke

Here is the situation I'm in:

I just implemented a DNN site. I already have a huge database table of users. Now when my users come in to register for my DNN site, they're **required** to put in a first name, last name and DOB. I will then use this information to match their records to the existing user table via a SQL query. The only problem is I can't find "DOB" field anywhere, in any table or for that matter most of the rest of the profile information. Is it even stored in the database? or am I just blind?

The best answer I could find was from a dnn forum which stated

> "User profile information is stored in several tables in the database. The 'Users' table  is the place to start for basic information. There are several tables that have "profile"  in the name that also are important."

I've looked through almost every table in the database, but with no luck...

I'm using DNN 6.0 with SQL Server 2008

I've looked everywhere but can't find it. Any help or guidance from anyone would be much appreciated! Even a paid solution like a pre-built module would work.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look in the `ProfilePropertyDefinition` table for the `PropertyDefinitionId` of the dateOfBirth property. Then, with that id, and the id of the user, you can query the `UserProfile` table to retrieve the value.

There is more at this blog post
http://erikvanballegoij.com/Home/itemid/28/Selecting-profile-properties-the-easy-way

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The blog post really clarified a lot of questions I had.